# Match integer values from end of string until second dot

Tags: python, string

I have following string `GA1.2.4451363243.9414195136` and I want to match `4451363243.9414195136` using regular expression for python.

I have tried the following which is not working `([\d].[\d])$`

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: have you tried `endswith` string function ?

Comment: I need regex only, this is to be used in one of the tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex `([0-9]+.[0-9]+)$` matches the expected part of the example. Note that more specific solutions may arise as you provide more details, restrictions, etc. regarding the part to be matched:

```
>>> import re
>>> data = "GA1.2.4451363243.941419513"
>>> re.findall(r"([0-9]+.[0-9]+)$", data)
['4451363243.941419513']
```

It requests the matched part to be made of:

- digit(s)
- dot
- digit(s)
- end of line.

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas (string operations or regex):

```
s = 'GA1.2.4451363243.9414195136'

out = '.'.join(s.rsplit('.', 2)[-2:])
# '4451363243.9414195136'

import re
out = re.search(r'[^.]*\.[^.]*$', s)
# <re.Match object; span=(6, 27), match='4451363243.9414195136'>
```

*NB. to ensure matching digits, you can replace `[^.]` (any character but `.`) with `\d`.*

For an arbitrary N:

```
N = 3

out = '.'.join(s.rsplit('.', N)[-N:])
# '2.4451363243.9414195136'

out = re.search(fr'[^.]*(?:\.[^.]*){{{N-1}}}$', s)
# <re.Match object; span=(4, 27), match='2.4451363243.9414195136'>
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be done using pure python! but if you want to use regex here is the code:

regex:

```
(?:[\w\d]*.){2}(.*)
```

python:

```py
import re
s = 'GA1.2.4451363243.9414195136'
re.match(r'(?:[\w\d]*.){2}(.*)',s).groups()[0]   # output: '4451363243.9414195136'
```

## OR

Just use python:

```py
s.split('.',2)[-1]    # output: '4451363243.9414195136'
```